# Задержка выполнения скрипта на Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Делаю мега-мега меню.Заметил что при переходе з главного пунка меню к последнему дочернему по диагонали блок пропадает.Решил решить это задержкой на секунду,пол секунды чтоб пользователь успел навести к последнему пункту.Как можно реализовать задержку?
Сейчас имеется вот такой вот код

```
  $('.mega-mnu ul li').hover(function () {
  var mega_inner  = $(this).find('ul');
   mega_inner.css({'display':'block'});
},
 function () {
     $('.mega-mnu ul li i').remove();
     var mega_inner  = $(this).find('ul');
     mega_inner.css({'display':'none'}).delay(5000);
 }
);
```

http://codepen.io/jSas/pen/LbavKz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения проблемы вам нужно анализировать направление движения курсора мыши: если курсор движется вертикально, то открывать пункты меню в обычном режиме, а если горизонтально или по диагонали - игнорировать перемещение над соседними пунктами меню.

Определение направления курсора можно реализовать следующим образом. Добавьте перед вашим кодом следующий фрагмент:

```
var prevPageX = 0;
var isVerticalDirection = true;
var directionTimer = 0;
$('.mega-mnu ul').mousemove(function(e) {    
    if (directionTimer) {
       return false;
    }  
    directionTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        // в данном случае считается, что курсор движется не по вертикали,
        // если за время 50 миллисекунд его горизонтальное смещение больше 10 пикселей
        isVerticalDirection = Math.abs(e.pageX - prevPageX) < 10;
        clearTimeout(directionTimer);
        directionTimer = 0;
        prevPageX = e.pageX;
    }, 50);    
});
```

И измените свой код следующим образом:

```
$('.mega-mnu ul li').hover(function () {
      if (isVerticalDirection) {
        $(this).css({'color':'#000'});
        $(this).parent().find('li > ul:visible').hide();

        var mega_inner  = $(this).find('ul');
         mega_inner.css({'display':'block'});        
      }

  },
     function () {
        if (isVerticalDirection) {
          var mega_inner  = $(this).find('ul');
          mega_inner.css({'display':'none'});
      }         
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function(){
//some code here   
}, 1000)
```

Comment: В моем случае ето не работает получается каша.